# Difference between php & Js

Tags: javascript, php, html

So we got 2 types of tags which my lecture finds me wrong of using when we talking about php

Which one belongs to the other ?

```
<body>
<script src="myPhp.php">
Echo
</script>
</body>
```

&

```
<body>
<?php
Echo
 ?>
</body>
```

My lecturer is marking me wrong for using the first tag in my php exam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<script src="xxxx"></script>` statement in a HTML file is used for including an external Javascript (JS) file, such as

```
<script src="myscripts.js"></script>
```

to include another PHP file (in a PHP file), you need something like

```
<?php include "myPhp.php"; ?>
```

Please note that Javascript is a client-side language and PHP is a server-side language, so make sure you understand what you are trying to accomplish when using them.

For further reference, you may see [what-is-the-use-of-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3497115/what-is-the-use-of-javascript) and [what is PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro-whatis.php) and other related articles